# add select options using ajax to selectize.js

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am trying to add options to selectbox using ajax. I am using selectize.js. If i dont use selectize.js every thing works fine. Both selectbox are linked when one select is updated other selectbox values get updated using ajax(hope u got the point). 
My HTML & javascript ajax code is:

```
<label class="uk-form-label" for="wizard_device_catagory">Device Catagory*</label>
<select id="wizard_device_catagory" name="devicetype" onchange="showmanuf(this.value);getproblems(this.value,idpriority.value);" required>
    <option value="">Select category</option>
    <option value="mobile">Mobile</option>
    <option value="tablet">Tablet</option>
    <option value="laptop">Laptop</option>
    <option value="pc">PC</option>
    <option value="printer">Printer</option>
    <option value="ups">UPS</option>
</select>
<div class="parsley-row">
    <label class="uk-form-label" for="manufacturerdrop">Manufacturer*</label> 
    <select id="manufacturerdrop" name="manufacturer" onchange="getmodel(this.value,devicetype.value);">
        <option value="">Select Manufacturer</option>
    </select>
</div>

function showmanuf(first){  
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {         
         if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("manufacturerdrop").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;       
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","php/getmanufacturer.php?first="+first,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
};
```

I have never used selectize.js but i want to use selectize.js. pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options should be added using the `addOption()` function, not injected directly with HTML manipulation. Once the options have been added, you must then call the `refreshOptions()` function to update the UI.

Instead of `addOption()`, you could also use the `options` configuration option, which expects an array of values to be injected as `<option>` tags. You would, in this case, also need to set the `dataAttr` and `valueField` configuration options.

This is all according to their API documentation: https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md

Comment: I'm guessing it would be like: `$('#select-item')[0].selectize.addOption('some value');`